# How to consume WinRT IAsyncOperation* object in "native c++" environment

Tags: c++, asynchronous, windows-runtime

I have C/C++ SDK library which should be ported to Windows 8 Metro (WinRT).
Library is mostly OS-independent, but it contains some modules which interact with hardware using OS-provided APIs.

While porting it to WinRT I've decided to try to use WRL instead of C++/CX as much as possible. So right now I can create and consume most of the required WinRT objects.
But I've faced absolute obstacle while working with Async objects, provided by WinRT.

For example, I use following code to enumerate HW devices:

```
// create interface to "static" members of DeviceInformation class
ComPtr<IDeviceInformationStatics>   DeviceInformationStatics;
HRESULT hr = GetActivationFactory(HString::MakeReference(RuntimeClass_Windows_Devices_Enumeration_DeviceInformation).Get(), &DeviceInformationStatics);

ComPtr<IAsyncOperation<DeviceInformationCollection*>> operation;
hr = DeviceInformationStatics->FindAllAsyncDeviceClass( DeviceClass_All, &operation);
```

At this point I have valid IAsyncOperation pointer. I thought it can be used like that:

```
task<ComPtr<DeviceInformationCollection*>> tsk(operation);
```

but I failed, because task<> constructor which accepts IAsyncOperation is declared under "#if defined(__cplusplus_winrt)" in ppltasks.h, which, in turn, depends on /ZW compiler option.

How I'm supposed to use IAsyncOperation object in this case? Actually, I only need to wait for operation to be completed.

Answer (score 4):

Just in case someone else is looking for this in C++/WinRT:

```
    auto asyncOp = someFunctionReturningIAsyncOperation();

    asyncOp.Completed([](auto &&result, auto && status) {
        // do whatever with result and status
    });
```

Comment: It is better to use `co_await` than explicitly setting the completion delegate.

Comment: @ChrisGuzak assuming it is even available. I'm building C++/WinRT code using Clang, and uses of co_await with it had the compiler emit a pretty spooky "Instruction does not dominate all uses! […] fatal error: error in backend: Broken function found, compilation aborted!". It doesn't even works when building for 32 bits because the coroutine_traits for IAsyncOperation assumes that lambdas can convert to function pointers with a specific calling convention, which it cannot on Clang.

Answer (score 1):

From my C++/CX experience, what you can do is you can construct an `AsyncOperationCompletedHandler<DeviceInformationCollection*>` object, initialize it with a member function in your class, and assign it to the `Completed` property of the IAsyncOperation.

In C++/CX, you just construct the `AsyncOperationCompletedHandler<>` object with two parameters - `this` from the calling class, and a pointer-to-member to a callback method. Like this:

```
MyAsyncOp->Completed = ref new AsyncOperationCompletedHandler<ResultType ^>(this, &MyClass::OnDone);
```

where OnDone is defined thus:

```
void MyClass::OnDone(IAsyncOperation<ResultType ^> ^AsOp, AsyncStatus s)
{
     ResultType ^Result = AsOp->GetResults();
}
```

I'm not sure how to call constructors in WRL. You figure this one out.

Also, the completion handler will be called on a random thread. If you need to pass something back to the UI thread, `Dispatcher->RunAsync()` is your friend. Most XAML classes have a Dispatcher member in them.

EDIT: now that I'm looking at samples, there seems to be a non-managed helper class called `Callback` that you construct around a `this` and a pointer-to-member. Look it up. Still not sure how to connect one to an IAsyncOperation though...

Comment: Thanks, will try it. I wasn't sure about race condition when i set 'Completed' handler _after_ operation has completed.

Comment: I wouldn't worry about race conditions. Since there's no way to get an IAsyncOperation with a completion handler preset from the beginning, they must've taken care of the situation when the operation completes before the handler is set. The potential for race condition in the naive implementation is way, way too obvious.

Answer (score 1):

This is an old question... But in case anyone needs the answer like I did:

The [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh973451.aspx) shows how to accomplish this in native C++. It's pretty straightforward. You initialize the WRL runtime, the object you're interested in and then create an event and callback handler that will be called when the event fires.

Answer (score 0):

If the <strike>library</strike> hardware-specific module already works on Win32, I suggest you keep it that way.  Install a Win32 service to interact with the hardware, and then the Metro app just needs to communicate with the service (many IPC options, such as sockets, pipes, I'm sure you can find one that works well even in the restricted Metro sandbox).

Comment: SDK is cross-platform and should work on ARM-based devices with Windows 8. Don't sure that win32 will be available in this case.

Comment: @Zakhar: Sorry, I mean just the module that's hardware-specific.

Answer (score -1):

IAsyncOperation is an awaitable type, so you should you use the equivalent of await, or call it's Result property.

Comment: await is a C++/CX keyword. The OP is asking for a native C++ solution.

Comment: C++ has `co_await` and C++ WinRT supports this making consumption eveneasier.